# Поиск по внешнему ключу в django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

как в Django admin сделать поиск по внешнему ключу.
Есть модель:

```py
class LocationPrinter(models.Model):
    serialNamber = models.ForeignKey(Printer, models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Серийный номер')
    numberRoom = models.CharField(verbose_name='Номер кабинета', max_length=10)
    typeRoom = models.ForeignKey(TypeRoom, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Тип помещения')
    numberTutul = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Номер титула')
    floor = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Этаж')
    zone = models.ForeignKey(Zone, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Зона')
    dateChange = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Дата', auto_now=True)
```

Необходимо сделать поиск по serialNamber(внешний ключ)
в файле Admin.py пишу следуючщий код:

```py
class LocAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('serialNamber','numberRoom','typeRoom','numberTutul','floor','zone', 'dateChange')
    search_fields = ['serialNamber']
```

Начинаю поиск выходит следующая ошибка: `Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains`

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: Покажите код модели, на которую ссылается внешний ключ

Comment: `serialNamber__name` где имя поля из Printer

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, очень помогли